# Input's with bootstrap icons

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, styles, icons

I'm trying to make a button which connects to a mumble server. I'm using bootstrap for the CSS at the moment.

In my quick mock up I did earlier I had this button with the headphones icon, however I can't figure out to do it as the connect button requires the  tag instead of the  tag.

Here is a working version of the button the way i would like it styled and one of a working version of the mumble connect button.

Is it possible to use the icon with the `<input>`?

Styled button;

> ```
> <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="button"><i class="icon-headphones icon-white"></i> Connect to Mumble</button>
> ```

Connection 'button';

```
<input class="button" value="Connect" onclick="window.location.href='mumble://MUMBLE IP HERE/?version=1.2.3'" type="BUTTON" />
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this-

```
       <div class="input-prepend">
        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-user icon-black"></i></span>
<input type="text" name="login" class="//Some class" placeholder="Email address"/>
         </div>
```

In case of appending it, Just replace `.input-prepend` with `.input-append`.

Example- http://jsfiddle.net/PYwq5/

**Update bootstrap V3-**

**Append**-

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        icon</span>
</div>
```

**Prepend**-

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        icon</span>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" />
</div>
```

**Demo**-  https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/9190/